# JQuery Dialog Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I'm using a **JQuery Dialog** and I'm having problems positioning it on my screen.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="useAgency" title="Fill Shift Using Agency">
<!-- Modal Info Here-->
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('div#useAgency').dialog({ autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 250,
        position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

The Modal is hidden by default. Once I click a link the following JQuery code is called which then opens up the Modal.

```
$("#confirmAgency").click(function () {
        $("#useAgency").dialog('open');
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'black');
    });
```

The Modal is placed in the centre of the page when opened, but if the user has scrolled near the bottom of the page and the clicks to open the Modal, the Modal then opens at the bottom of the page almost of out sight.

I've tried adding the position element to my Dialog declaration, but it still isn't working.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check your page for any broken markup ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this CSS on modal body:

```
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

I've had to use a setter method  of the dialog object, on click event, like in  http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "position", { my: "center", at: "center center", of: window } );

In my case, i put on the center of the screen, but off course you can set at other place.